# SC_MONITORPOWER starts background tasks

Tags: windows, background, task, hiccup

**Summary**

When putting the monitor in sleep mode in Windows 10, Windows seems to execute some tasks that don't get executed with the screen on.
This is interfering with our software, and we need to get rid of it.

**Ful story**

For a hardware device with a touch screen, I need to be able to turn off the touch screen when it's not in use, for durability reasons. Windows has a message that you can send to turn it off, SC_MONITORPOWER. More specifically:
`SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);`

This works fine, but when the screen is off, Windows is apparently sometimes performing some tasks that it doesn't do when the screen is on. We are careful to never write anything to the screen in this situation (that causes huge problems when the screen is off, in fact just having a blinking cursor in a DOS box is using up half a core when the screen is off).

Our software requires a callback to be executed every 0.25 ms. We have turned nearly every task, service and several other things in Windows off, and with the screen on, I can run our software for days without ever missing a callback. But with the screen off I get hiccups. The callback already runs at the highest possible priority.

So there is apparently something that we missed when we turned all services and tasks off. There appear to be 2 causes of hiccups:

- One happens once every 10-30 hours or so (not sure of the exact time, it seems to vary). But it always happens 5 times, with EXACTLY 5 minutes (at most a few milliseconds off) in between (so in total it happens 5 times in a 25 minute period).
- Beside this, we get a single hiccup typically every 4-10 hours, but the time between occurrences doesn't seem to be very constant so there could also be multiple causes.

I'm a bit at a loss here, and running analysis software can easily interfere with our own software, making it harder to detect when these hiccups really occur and when they are caused by running the analysis software.

Interestingly, I have seen this 5-times-every-5-minutes thing also on a completely different system (different hardware, different OS version), when recording audio in Adobe Audition. Audition misses pieces of audio every 5 minutes in this case, and I think it also only happens when the monitor is in sleep mode and you're not logged in remotely.

We have already tried to turn the touch screen off using direct monitor commands like Nircmd does, and it doesn't support those. My guess is that the SC_MONITORPOWER message is triggering more things in Windows, and if we can turn them off, that would fix our problem. Any ideas?

**System**
Intel i5-8700 with 6 cores, Windows LTSB, no extra software installed except our own.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, problem solved. It was not an extra task that was being started, it was one of the existing Windows processes that for some reason only causes issues when the display is off. Since killing them is not an option (Windows will just restart them), I've suspended the following processes, and the culprit is one of these (I don't know which one yet):

- sihost.exe
- igfxEM.exe (I very much suspect this one)
- RuntimeBroker.exe
- dllhost.exe
- taskhostw.exe
- explorer.exe

I have to continue testing a bit longer to be absolutely certain, but so far with these tasks all suspended I've not seen a missed callback in the last 38 hours. I don't know yet if there are any drawbacks to suspending all these things, so I'll try to find the cause(s) and suspend only that/those.